# Can not start mysqld, unsupported engine InnoDB

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, innodb, ubuntu-14.04, mysql-cluster

I am trying to start mysqld on one of my data nodes in NDBCluster.  The node connects to the management server correctly, but when trying to start mysqld, the start fails when it encounters an old InnoDB table I have.  I have edited my.cnf to include

```
[mysqld]  
innodb=OFF
default-storage-engine=ndbcluster
```

and these changes are noted in the output of the mysqld start, yet it continues to fail when encountering the InnoDB table later.  Any thoughts?
Included below is the output of

```
mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf

2015-11-02 11:43:11 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-11-02 11:43:11 6089 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.7-linux-glibc2.5-i686/data/tigershark.lower-test
2015-11-02 11:43:11 6089 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.7-linux-glibc2.5-i686/data/tigershark.lower-test
2015-11-02 11:43:11 6089 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)

2015-11-02 11:43:11 6089 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_cache: 431 (requested 2000)

2015-11-02 11:43:11 6089 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-11-02 11:43:11 6089 [Warning] The option innodb (skip-innodb) is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
2015-11-02 11:43:11 6089 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
2015-11-02 11:43:11 6089 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2015-11-02 11:43:11 6089 [Note] NDB: Changed global value of binlog_format from STATEMENT to MIXED
2015-11-02 11:43:11 6089 [Note] NDB: NodeID is 5, management server '10.0.1.211:1186'
2015-11-02 11:43:12 6089 [Note] NDB[0]: NodeID: 5, all storage nodes connected
2015-11-02 11:43:12 6089 [Warning] NDB: server id set to zero - changes logged to bin log with server id zero will be logged with another server id by slave mysqlds
2015-11-02 11:43:12 6089 [Note] Starting Cluster Binlog Thread
2015-11-02 11:43:12 6089 [Note] NDB Binlog: Ndb object created with reference : 0x80040005, name : Ndb Binlog schema change monitoring
2015-11-02 11:43:12 6089 [Note] NDB Binlog: Ndb object created with reference : 0x80050005, name : Ndb Binlog data change monitoring
2015-11-02 11:43:12 6089 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-11-02 11:43:12 6089 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-11-02 11:43:12 6089 [Note] Binlog end
2015-11-02 11:43:12 6089 [Note] Stopping Cluster Utility thread
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Stopping Cluster Binlog
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Stopping Cluster Index Stats thread
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ndb_transid_mysql_connection_map'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ndbinfo'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ndbcluster'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Stopping Cluster Index Statistics thread
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-11-02 11:43:13 6089 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire tree needs to have suitable file/directory permissions for `mysqld`.

Also, you should probably allow MySQL to open more than 1024 files.